# How to stop .sh file printing shell as sh not zsh (used to be 'How to figure out the shell of a terminal with .sh language'

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am new to the shell coding language, and would like to know if it is possible to find out  what shell someone is using (i.e. Bash, zsh, fish), and echoing some text (i.e. alias command) to that shells' config file.

Thanks in advance,
Gomenburu

Edit: I have fixed the main problem, which is finding the command that reveals the shell, but when I put it in a .sh file, it gives a strange output (I am using zsh):

Code- in file which is named test.sh:

```
echo $0
```

Output:

```
./test.sh
```

But in a normal environment (so not from a file), my input is:

```
echo $0
```

And my output is:
`zsh`

What is happening?

Comment: ah yes, the $0 variable will give you the script name if run from inside a script and the shell name if run from the terminal. Try using my first example. In the script you can set a SHELL variable to the output of the command using back-ticks, like this: SHELL=`ps -p $$ | grep -v CMD | awk '{print $4}'\`

Comment: If you'd like to know the user's preferred choice of interactive shell, use the `$SHELL` environment variable. A `./test.sh` script is likely run with whatever `/bin/sh` points to which is often a different thing. If sourced instead of run, it might use the user's shell but writing a script that works for all different shells is not possible unless kept very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to pull this info using the $0 or $$ variable

1. using the $$ variable with ps. by itself it give too much info, so i added grep -v to remove header line and awk to pull the last value

   $ ps -p $$
   $ ps -p $$ | grep -v CMD | awk '{print $4}'
2. using the $0 variable, seem easier

   $ echo $0

Let me know if this doesn't work for you.